# SFTP mounting Error with Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: sftp, mount, cloud9-ide

Currently, I was only able to get a vanilla FTP mount to work with Cloud9.  Here's the error I got:

An error occured while creating mount:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"status":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid Flags: 'Times -o 
auto_cache,transform_symlinks,StrictHostKeyChecking=no,reconnect,workaround=all,password_stdin
 -p 22 -C'","defaultMessage":"Bad Request"}}
```

Anyone else struggling with this?

We're trying to see if a shared SFTP drive can be used by two developers to collaboratively work on SASS files and use Cloud9 for compiling.

Comment: Hi Ross, would you be able to connect via support@c9.io and explain your issue in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same error when trying to mount an SFTP drive in Cloud9. Turns out spaces in the name was the culprit for me. Changed the name from Digital Ocean to Digital_Ocean and it mounted perfectly.